# Referenced Nuget DLL Not Found Working Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, nuget, visual-studio-2017

I added a Nuget library called Mpir.Net, which specializes in manipulating gigantic numbers much faster than the in-built BigInteger class does. When I added it in, Visual Studio 2017 was able to find the DLL, add it into my references, and provide suggestions based on the variables and functions defined in the DLL. Visual Studio was clearly able to find the DLL, unlike many questions on here from people with similar problems.

The problem is that when I run the program, it says xmpir64.dll not found, even though Visual Studio can reference things inside it in the code editor.

I've tried changing the target .NET version to no avail. What is the problem?
As a side note, I'm very new to C# and Visual Studio, so please keep that in mind when answering. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKHzg.jpg) is a link to a picture of my solution explorer.

Comment: Could you also include the properties view for the Mpir.Net.dll file included in your project?

Comment: @CodexNZ I got it working. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mpir.Net is a wrapper around an unmanaged library (GMP). When it says it's unable to find the DLL, it's because it's looking for the unmanaged one (xmpir64.dll) which is in your project folder (not the managed one in the references, which is the wrapper).

You probably just need to click on xmpir64.dll (and the x32 one too), look at its properties in the bottom right, and ensure copy to output directory is set to "copy always".

As a side note, Mpir.NET does not dispose of its unmanaged resources correctly, so don't be surprised if you have a big memory leak. I don't think I'd use it for commercial code.

Comment: I've been going through 50 hoops to find a fast BigInteger library that supports decimals. Do you know of any for C# that don't have any major drawbacks? I didn't know that Mpir had memory leak issues. I'm not using this for commercial application, but I am using it for pretty memory heavy stuff. Should I just use the inbuilt BigInteger?

Comment: It worked! Why is it that I havee to set it to copy always?

Comment: That's what we ended up doing, but we were working integers with under 256 bits. We were also needing to create and destroy a lot of them, and discovered the memory leak quite quickly.

Comment: It could also be "copy if newer" it doesn't matter in this case.

Comment: I'm trying to render a fractal, so I'm going to be using REALLY big numbers, but I can rewrite over all of the variables over and over. Would the memory leak be a problem?

Comment: The problem as I recall was that they did not implement Dispose properly if at all (from memory). I would give it a go and see how it works, if you're able to reuse the same variable or set of variables, the memory leak would not affect you.

Comment: I thought you might want to know that I found a way of using MPIR and MPFR inside C# without a memory leak (as far as I'm aware of). Basically, I built MPFR and MPIR from scratch for VS2017 using a Youtube tutorial. Then I used MPFRC++ to call that code in C++. Then I did all my calculations in C++, and I passed it to C# using C++/CLI. It's pretty convoluted and hard to set up, but it's still faster than any C# native implementation I've found.